# How would I subtract from a for loop in java without it ending up with negative one?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to print a string backward, but it doesn't start where I want it to. Whenever I run the code it says it starts at -1. Here's my code:

```
public static String reverse(String str)
    {
        //This method will return a string that reverses the letters in 'str'
        //Example:
        //   reverse("abcdef") returns "fedcba"
        String result="";

        for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
           result = result + str.substring(i-1, i);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

How would I get it to subtract 1 instead of it thinking it's a negative one?

Comment: you should use: `i > 0` not `i >= 0`

Comment: Try changing `str.substring(i-1, i)` to `str.substring(i, i+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a logic issue in the code.

Correct implementation should be

```
//using subString the way you are trying
public static String reverse(String str)
    {
       String result="";

        for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
           result = result + str.substring(i, i+1);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Alternative Approaches using charAt

```
public static String reverse(String str)
    {
        String result="";

        for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
           result +=str.charAt(i);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Using String Builder(Probably the best method if you are not writing he code for learning purpose)

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not splice characters one by one

```
for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    result += str.charAt(i);
}
```